# Make a generic InArray method in Java

Tags: java

I have the following code to check if a specific element is found in an array. I want this method to work with generic types.

```
public static <T> boolean InArray(T[] array, T needle) {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (needle == array[i]) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
```

But I can't figure out on how to call this function:

```
char[] arr = {'a', 'b', 'c'};
if (InArray(arr, 'c')) {
   // In array
}
```

Yields the following error:

```
'InArray(T[], T)' in ... cannot be applied to '(char[], char)'
```

How do I make this generic method work?

Comment: Primitives don't work well with generics. I believe you'd need a separate method for each primitive type, in addition to the generic object method (though I'm not sure the `T` adds value). You can see this pattern within the JDK (e.g. the `java.util.Arrays` class).

Comment: `Arrays.binarySearch` does what you want.

Comment: @markspace that only works on a sorted array

Answer (score 1):

To call the method *InArray*, you need to wrap(box) your arguments to **Character** class. The below code explains how to call the method.

```
    Character arr1[] = {'a', 'b', 'c'};
    if (InArray(arr1, Character.valueOf('c'))) {
       // In array
    }
```

This is because you have array type as one of the parameters, the other primitive type parameter will not auto box to Character class. So you need to box the primitive type manually.

Answer (score 0):

Personally if I'm going to be comparing objects against my array. I use an arrayList. This allows you to use the 'contain' method

```
ArrayList<T> myArray = new ArrayList<>();

//Add your objects

if (myArray.contains(other_T_object)) {
    //do stuff if condition is met
}
```

The reason why you are getting that error, is because your InArray method takes in an array of T objects as the first parameter and a single T object as your second parameter. You can't pass in an array of Char, because those are not specified in your methods declaration.

Your method will have to look like this.

```
public static boolean InCharArray(char[] array, char needle) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (needle == array[i]) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Also, note if they were using a `Character[]` array then their method would work fine. The problem is that generics do not work well with primitives, and especially not well with arrays whose component type is a primitive type.